# Чи правильно вживати слово "арфіст"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Одного разу після концерту почула вислів "арфіст чудово грав". Зразу виникло питання: "А чому арфіст, а не арф'яр?". Чи не буде це калькою до рос."арфист"? Знайшла це слово у [Матеріалі з Вікісловника](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%84%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82), але тут  інформації майже немає. [Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/arfist) подає лише слово "арфіст", а "арф'яр"- ні. Як тоді правильно ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сучасний [Словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1642&page=74) подає 2 статті про значення цього слова:

> **АРФІ́СТ**, а, ч. Музикант, який грає на арфі.
>
> Арфіст грав натхненно (з газ.).

Оскільки цей словник не подає слова "арф’яр", вводимо "арф’ярка" і видає таку статтю:

> АРФ'Я́РКА див. арф'я́нка. АРФ'Я́НКА, АРФ'Я́РКА, и, ж., *заст*. Арфістка.
>
> На другий вечір зібрався до Штемберга в садок трохи не увесь город подивитися на чудо садове – на писану красу арф'янки (Панас Мирний);
>
> *Арф'ярка видивилася на нього, а її пальці тим часом машинально забігали по струнах** (І. Франко).

Про використання суфікса [-іст](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky) читаємо, що у пункті № 56. є відсилання до -ист.

> 44. -ист, -иста, -іст на означення носія професії, вмілости, або приналежности людини до чогось (тут спалися два наростки український -ист і чужомовний -іст: бандурист (старіша форма бандуриста), цимбалист (-иста, -истий), басиста і деякі інші, але тепер здебільшого цей наросток вживається як чужомовний, отже то як -ист, то як -іст: юрист, артист..., спеціяліст..., навіть україніст, боротьбіст...

Щодо суфікса [-яр](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky), то знаходимо інформацію у пункті № 17:

> -ар, -яр — дуже поширений наросток на означення особи певної професії; найчастіше при іменникових пнях: байкар, бляхар, біляр, вівчар, віспар, кобзар, штукар, дзвонар, злидар, книгар, скотар, пачкар, чоботар, дояр, плугар (плуга́тар), тесляр, коминяр, вапняр, голяр, повістяр, газетяр, скляр, лі́кар, то́кар, пи́сар, бо́ндар...

За анологією і арфіст.

Отже, вживання слів “арфіст” та "арф’яр" - нормативне, проте якщо приглянутись до сучасного [Словника української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1642&page=74), на скільки я правильно зрозуміла, вімнінність у пропонованих Вами словах лише у тому, що суфікс -іст застарілий.